# How to allow short tags in php with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, php

how can I allow apache to use

```
'<?'
```

Now it understands only

```
'<?php'
```

---

Found answer: in php.ini short_open_tag should be On.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) configuration option.